# wx.SpinButton acceleration when holding down one of the buttons (up/down)

Tags: python, wxpython

Some GUI's libraries have spin button widget with optional feature - acceleration. 
When holding down one of the buttons (up or down) - as a result an acceleration of change in the value according to how long it is depressed.

Is this feature in [wx.SpinButton](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SpinButton-class.html) and what's the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a built in feature of the SpinButton. Note that the SpinButton isn't implemented cross-platform, so you might want to look at wx.SpinCtrl or FloatSpin. Anyway, to implement what you want, you could probably catch the wx.EVT_SPIN and start a wx.Timer. When the timer hits some pre-determined value, you could start updating the control yourself. I'm not sure if this would work as you would be trying to update a widget that is already being updated, but it might...

Of course, you'd also have to bind to the mouse up event to stop the timer and stop the updates. I suspect you my have to roll your own widget though...

I would ask on the wxPython mailing list. Someone there might have more ideas.